# Django update single field in model entry with request

Tags: django, django-forms

I try to update a model entry with a POST request.

```
<QueryDict: {u'is_locked': [u'False']}>
```

I tried with a model form :

```
modelEntry = model.get(pk=pk)
modelForm (request.POST, initial= modelEntry)
if modelForm.is_valid():
    modelForm.save()
```

This was not valid (csrf_exempt)..

And also tried without modelform, directly into the model :

```
model.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(**request.POST)
```

Nothing happen ..
Ideally I search a solution with modelform (to check and clean my datas before saving).

There is a proper way for this ?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `instance`, instead of `initial` to your model form so that it knows which object to update.

```
modelForm (request.POST, instance = modelEntry)
if modelForm.is_valid():
    modelForm.save()
```

Comment: In fact something happening now, but still not valid, I got form errors on others fields... But there is no change on them.

Comment: "attached_to - This field is required."

It's a ChoiceField (linked to a GenericForeignKey).

Comment: @MObject, you can exclude fields that you do not want to edit from the form. See model form docs.